# rss newfeed of a subpage but not the whole page

Tags: web, rss, social-networking, feed

1. Is it possible to get newfeed of the certain section of the webpage? e.g. i want to get the newfeed of this page

   http://gulfnews.com/business/property

but the newsfeed i get is of the whole page. Any help?

1. Is there any tool where i can control which posts to post and which to ignore. I am using http://www.rssgraffiti.com/ but it doesnt have a controlled option in the free package.

Answer (score 0):

If there content management system supported it, you could. But apparently there content management system doesn't support that.